# I am trying to get location information from ip address in JAVA but I am getting a java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error

Tags: java, sockets, servlets, geolocation, javaquery

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import javaQuery.importClass.javaQueryBundle;
import javaQuery.j2ee.GeoLocation;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class IP
 */
public class IP extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public IP() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
         System.out.println(ipAddress);

         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


            //Print out the IP address of the caller
            out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());


         GeoLocation $gl = javaQueryBundle.createGeoLocation();

         System.out.println(ipAddress);


            $gl.MAPTargetByIP(ipAddress, "test");
            System.out.println($gl.Latitude);
            System.out.println($gl.Longitude);
            System.out.println($gl.Country);
            System.out.println($gl.City);
            System.out.println($gl.State);
            System.out.println($gl.GoogleMap_URL);
            System.out.println($gl.GoogleMap_URL_Bubble);


    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

This is my code snippest.I am getting IP address of visitor but not location information.
    It gives :
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Or do you use proxy to access the internet?

Comment: Yes .. but i tried this after disabling firewall settings. But still same problem. I am using my organization proxy to access internet

Comment: Ahh I see your problem, the reason you are unable to access is because you are blocked by your organizational proxy. You need to work around with it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell the java code that all HTTP request should be routed through the proxy use the below snippet:

`System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxyHost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "proxyPort");
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
     public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return (new PasswordAuthentication("USERNAME","PASSWORD".toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);`

The System.setProperty sets the proxy host and port. The Authenticator should be your corporate username and password. This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.model.*;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.record.Location;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.record.MaxMind;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.record.RepresentedCountry;

import javaQuery.importClass.javaQueryBundle;
import javaQuery.j2ee.GeoLocation;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class IP
 */
public class IP extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public IP() {
        super();

        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxyHostName");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "proxyPort");
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
             public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return (new PasswordAuthentication("USERNAME","PASSWORD".toCharArray()));
            }
        };
        Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
         System.out.println(ipAddress);




         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


            //Print out the IP address of the caller
            out.println(request.getLocalAddr());



         GeoLocation $gl = javaQueryBundle.createGeoLocation();

         System.out.println($gl.toString().length());
         System.out.println("--");
         System.out.println($gl.getMACAddressWindows());


            $gl.MAPTargetByIP(ipAddress , "test");
            System.out.println($gl.Latitude);
            System.out.println($gl.Longitude);
            System.out.println($gl.Country);
            System.out.println($gl.City);
            System.out.println($gl.State);
            System.out.println($gl.GoogleMap_URL);
            System.out.println($gl.GoogleMap_URL_Bubble);


    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

This is working fine now.