# Exception in Connection time out for HttpURLConnection in Java programming

Tags: java, eclipse, httpurlconnection, connectexception

Here's the problem, I would like to write a Java program to increase the page hit for specific URL. And currently I just surfed in the Internet and get some basic program to do the testing. However, I even couldn't get the program running... Below is my program and related output.

Eclipse, Java program:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.baidu.com");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();

    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response code of the object is " + code);
    if (code == 200) {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
```

Below is the output:

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:245)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:232)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:488)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:407)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:542)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:246)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:319)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:336)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:980)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:921)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:846)
    at HttpRedirectExample2.main(HttpRedirectExample2.java:14)

I have searched many resources, and some of the suggestion is the firewall issue. However, i don't think my computer with this issue as I have succeed to write a program to open a IE browser and redirect to Google.

Is anyone help me to solve this problem?

**Current step, I am wondering whether is my proxy issue as I work for an company and the network is using in a proxy.**

And I am also welcome if you could provide any suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. It is a proxy issue. Configure you proxy using the solution given here:
[I am trying to get location information from ip address in JAVA but I am getting a java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284484/i-am-trying-to-get-location-information-from-ip-address-in-java-but-i-am-getting/23289354#23289354)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, after I added the code, still same output. `System.setProperty("my proxy address", "8080");` Did I also need user authenticator??

Comment: Yes.. if you are behind a company proxy. you probably also have authentication. try your domain credentials.. also ensure that your proxy port is as per your internet explorer setting

Comment: I have finally gave up the proxy issue, actually i could move to next step. (As I used a intranet fdqn to login.) How can i do like this: redirect the link 5 times within 1s? -> I would like to increase the page hit actually.

Comment: You could try to open  parallel threads and base them on a timer.. the time will start a new thread every 12 seconds.. Just a random thought..